# Is there any cross-browser javascript library to set and get opacity?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, cross-browser, frontend

```
#a_div {
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
   // IE 
    background:transparent;
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000050,endColorstr=#99000050);
   zoom: 1;
}
```

Is there any javascript library I can use to get and set opacity to html element.
Need handle Cross-browser problem.

Comment: Wow... this is like asking Oral Roberts if he knows a way to salvation.

Answer (score 7):

JQuery - crossbrowser JS framework?

```
$('#a_div').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

Comment: Other websites seem to agree that jQuery abstracts opacity over IE's filter-based opacity support.

Answer (score 1):

I always apply these 5 CSS elements, then you're safe in most browsers.

```
opacity: .75; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* IE lt 8 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=75)"; /* IE 8 */
-khtml-opacity: .75; /* Safari 1.x */
-moz-opacity: .75; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Prototype Javascript library](http://www.prototypejs.org/).

HTML:

```
<div id="something">Hello</div>
```

JS

```
$('something').setOpacity(0.5);
```